# Mean values of cell with unequal columns using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell, average

I have a cell with different columns as follow:

M =

```
[1x16 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x18 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x13 double]
[1x21 double]
[1x15 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x16 double]
[1x17 double]
[1x17 double]
```

I am looking to take an average looking like mean(M,1). 
Is it possible to do it using MATLAB?

Thanks

Comment: If you use the solution in the duplicate to put the values into an array, you can then use `nanmean(M,1)` to get the mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mean all the values, you can run the following command:

```
mean(cell2mat(M))
```

`cell2mat` transfer `M` to a matrix with dimensions of `1xn` which `n` is the number of all values in `M`, then `mean` function get the average of the all values.

Also, if you want to get means for each cell you can run the following:

```
cellfun(@mean,M)
```

this will get the `mean` for each matrix in each cell.

## Update

As the size of columns are not the same, to get the mean of each column, we can do like the following:

```
m = max(cellfun(@length,M)); // get the max length of the matrices
for i = 1 : length(M)
    M{i}(m+1) = 0
end
// mean of each column
means = mean(reshape(cell2mat(M), length(M), m + 1));
% in octav: 
% means = mean(reshape(cell2mat(M), m + 1, length(M))');
means = means(1:m);
```

For more details, first we resize all arrays into the same size. After that, merge them into a matrix using `cell2mat`, and remove the extra column which was added to facilitate our computation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am in doubt that I can use mean(cell2mat(M)) because I need to have the same column for each cell and if I do so It gives me the error "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent "

Comment: I want to have the mean of all first columns and so on till the end, the solution that you provided to me only calculate the mean for each cell.

Comment: I run your code for a simple exmaple , i expected the average of first four  coulm would be 2 3 4 5 respectively. but it did not work: v1 = [2 3 4 5];
v2 = [2 3 4 5 6 7]; 
v3=  [2 3 4 5 6 7]; 
M={v1,v2,v3}
 
m = max(cellfun(@length,M)); %% get the max length of the matrices
for i = 1 : length(M)
    M{i}(m+1) = 0
end
%// mean of each column
means = mean(reshape(cell2mat(M), length(M), m + 1));
means = means(1:m);
  result: 3.0000    1.6667    1.6667    5.0000    3.0000    4.0000 ..for me the code output is not what I expected.

Comment: @Julliette I think you use octav. anyhow, I've update my solution. You should replace `means` with this: `means = mean(reshape(cell2mat(M), m + 1, length(M))');`